# Is is possible to control the speed and scrolling of a UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got custom tableview cells that are 170 px tall.  Including the table header I can see two complete cells and a portion of the third.  When I scroll the tableview, the cells shift up but do not stop until a portion of the third is above the table.

Is it possible to change the way the table scrolls and allow me to see all of the third cell.  A video illustrating the issue is available at https://youtu.be/iuhuR_wDe90

Images of the issue:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have enabled 'pagination' on your UITableView.

You can get rid of this in Interface Builder, in the Scroll View section there's an option called 'Paging Enabled' which should be switched off.

If you don't use storyboards, `tableView.pagingEnabled = NO;` will do the trick as well (though it is NO already by default).